# Ubuntu terminal displays a message each time it is opened: "bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, bash, java, openjdk

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 18. I have completely uninstalled OpenJdk8 following these steps:

```
    sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
    sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openjdk*
    sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
    sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove openjdk*
```

There is no line like refering to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` in:

- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile`
- `$HOME/.bashrc`
- `$HOME/.bash_profile`
- `$HOME/.bash_login`
- `$HOME/.profile`

So, how do I solve the issue of this message showing each time I open Ubuntu terminal ?

```
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The line in your terminal reads “is a directory” not “no such file or directory”

Comment: There could be a custom command specified in your terminal preferences.

Comment: You can try resetting the terminal preferences: `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal`

Comment: Can you login as a different user? This will show whether the error is coming from the user config or from system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running .bashrc in debug mode: 
$ bash -x ~/.bashrc 
and see if that shows up where the error is occurring. Otherwise you need to go through the script files and see if any command is running a java based script.

try creating a second user account. Log in to this and see if the same error occurs when opening a terminal. That will determine if this is local to your account or global to all accounts. That at least narrows the search!